# yarn install linking dependencies is slow every time using docker-compose

Tags: performance, docker, docker-compose, filesystems, yarnpkg

I am not very familiar working with docker, this is part of a large enterprise app that's moving the dev environment to docker.

Right now, `yarn install` *outside of docker* takes about **10 minutes** to complete, this is mainly done in `Linking Dependencies...` step, as there are over 30k objects to link I guess. After the first `yarn install`, it takes only **1 second** to complete. If I change one dependency, it takes about **10 seconds** to complete. So it's much faster than 10 minutes!

But *inside of docker* it takes about **5-10 minutes *every time***, no matter if dependencies change or not.

Any ideas why this is happening?

We use docker-compose and have several disparate processes, one of which is a node server. The node server runs yarn install whenever the package.json changes, but this is rather frequent (it gets updated several times daily). So yarn install runs several times a day. Ideally this would be as fast as running it outside of docker, but I'm not sure where to begin looking. Is there a setting or something that is removing the yarn cache on every `docker-compose restart node`, or what?

We have basically this in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  ...
  node:
    image: myimage:latest
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:cached
      - ./node_modules_docker:/app/node_modules:cached
    working_dir: /app
    ...
  ...
```

Comment: On some platforms (notably MacOS) using volumes like this is very very slow.  I’d remove these `volumes:`; for live development use Node on your host system, for pre-deployment integration testing run `docker build` to build a self-contained container including the application and its library dependencies.

Comment: @DavidMaze Is there no way to have the dev system be a mirror of the prod system and have it be as performant?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the latest "Docker Desktop for Mac Edge" version somehow optimizes how the files are shared.

Using the latest version (2.5.3 today):
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/edge-release-notes/

Now, running `yarn install` in docker seems to be as fast as running it on my mac.

Hope it'll help someone.

**EDIT 2021/02/26 :**

I kept docker up to date (3.x) and somehow I experimented very slow yarn install again.

Using Docker 2.5.4 (edge) makes things fast again :
https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/docker-for-mac/edge-release-notes.md